# Is there a way to set application-specific 'hot corners' in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, tweaks, shortcut

OS X's 'hot corners' feature is great, but I'd like to use it in just one specific application - or, set a specific hot corner action for one app, and a *different* action (for the same corner) in another app.

Is there a tool that can do this?

The tool [CornerClick](http://lifehacker.com/5907440/cornerclick-adds-more-actions-to-os-xs-hot-corners-saves-you-from-accidentally-activating-them) seems to have a lot of custom features over OS X's own one, but from a [brief look](https://gschueler.github.io/CornerClick/) it doesn't seem it offers a way to actually isolate/customize hot corners to specific apps per se.

Answer (score 4):

### CornerClick and AppleScript

Try creating an AppleScript that is triggered by CornerClick. Your AppleScript could check which [application is front most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613293/how-to-get-name-of-frontmost-app-with-applescript-and-use-it-to-get-the-filepath) and act accordingly.

### Enhancement Request

Also, consider opening an [enhancement request with CornerClick](https://github.com/gschueler/CornerClick/issues). The project is open source and your interest may help motivate the author, or other developers, to improve the product.